# pagination issue with MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

for paging I use paglist, but am wonder will I need to retrieve all the data from the server which will cause a big issue

any idea how to retrieve small data from server too and interact with pagelist now I do soemthing like

```
    int itemsPerPage = 25;
    int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
    List<Lucky> luckyGuids =serviceobject,ReturnData(); // this will return 10000 record

    return View(luckyGuids.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25));
```

but the problem is that a headache for the server , how can I return small data and keep track on the number of pages

Comment: first get 25 records and store 25th record id in ``temp`` and next time get 25 records in where put ``id > temp``

Comment: and how I get the paging work if the list is only 25 and cannot set total number of record

Comment: `ToPagedList()` works fine in your case. I think you just need to order before returning to the view.

Comment: @lnanikian the problem is in retrieing large data from server and if I retrieved a small data how to know the total number of pages

Comment: To know the total number of pages you can count your List of small data and divide by the number of items to display.

Comment: say a searhc result show 10000 record u want to retrieve only the first 20 and keep the total number with u

Comment: Could you show the code of your view please?